Internal Server Error 500 - Trying to connect to a language studio single classification model from a function app
I am trying to connect to an azure language studio model and obtain its prediction of a single category using a function app. It works from Testing deployments but gives me - 500 internal server error - when I try to connect to it from the function even though it looks like I have given it all the parameters required copied from Get prediction URL on the model. Here is the logging.info:
{'tasks': [{'kind': 'CustomSingleLabelClassification', 'parameters': {'projectName': 'ClassifyLab', 'deploymentName': 'ClasLab'}}], 'displayName': 'CustomTextPortal_CustomSingleLabelClassification', 'analysisInput': {'documents': [{'id': 'document_CustomSingleLabelClassification', 'text': 'Mother', 'language': 'en'}]}}

2024-06-17T03:29:47Z [Error] Executed 'Functions.OpGroupAILauncher' (Failed, Id=57c307a3-ec63-4041-81d7-ce3a2822534a, Duration=81ms)


go to invocations tab and check the latest logs for error counts.
